# How much $\frac{dp/dt}{p-900}=\frac{1}{2}$ become $\frac{d}{dt}\ln|p-900|=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, chain-rule

So I'm going through the examples in my Diff. Eqs. book before I tackle the homework (Boyce/DiPrima) and in 1.2 Example 1 they invoke the chain rule to go from $\frac{dp/dt}{p-900}=\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{d}{dt}\ln|p-900|=\frac{1}{2}$.

I consider myself pretty familiar with the chain rule but I can't follow this step.

Comment: Assuming $p$ is a function of $t$, what happens when you differentiate the latter equation's left hand side with respect to $t$?

Comment: It becomes the left hand side of the previous equation, which seems to verify that this is the correct way to go.  I was hoping to learn how to do it directly with the chain rule though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can look at it is by integrating and differentiating the LHS (in that order). You probably know that for a function $f(x)$,
$$f(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right]$$
So given
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}}{p-900}&=\frac{1}{2}\\[1ex]
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left[\int\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}}{p-900}\,\mathrm{d}t\right]&=\frac{1}{2}\\[1ex]
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left[\int\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{p-900}\right]&=\frac{1}{2}\\[1ex]
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\ln|p-900|&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}$$
where the second to last line's integral can be approached via a substitution, say $u=p-900$, which is essentially the reverse of the chain rule for differentiation.