# How are the two following fractions equal: $\frac{\frac{dp}{dt}}{p-500} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{d}{dt}\ln|{p-900}|=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$\frac{\frac{dp}{dt}}{p-500} = \frac{1}{2}$ equal to $\frac{d}{dt}\ln|{p-900}|=\frac{1}{2}$

I can see how this happens when I separate variables, but the book just says the following sentence: "By the chain rule the left side of Eq. (6) is the derivative of ln |p − 900| with respect to t, so we
have"

I don't seem to understand what is happening here with the chain rule. Any help?

Comment: Is one of the sides really supposed to include 500 while the other includes 900?  That's got to be a typo (possibly in the solutions or possibly in the problem statement.)

Comment: Related:  [How much $\frac{dp/dt}{p-900}=\frac{1}{2}$ become $\frac{d}{dt}\ln|p-900|=\frac{1}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621161/how-much-fracdp-dtp-900-frac12-become-fracddt-lnp-900-frac?rq=1)